# Operating on class members instead of passing parameters to methods

Tags: php, function, oop, methods

This is something I've been trying to find a good convention for, but are there particular cases in which I would want to pass variables to a method, over just operating straight on the class members, or vice versa? For example, let's say I have a simple class that just calculates the total price of something (forgive the super lame example):

```
class TaxCalculator
{
    protected $tax_rate = 0.07;
    protected $price = 10;

    public function callCalculate()
    {
        $this->calculate();
    }

    public function calculate()
    {
        return $this->price * ( 1 + $this->tax_rate );
    }
}
```

I know this isn't a real world example, but in this case, the main focus is on the `callCalculate()` method. Would you typically do it like this, pass in parameters to the `calculate()` method, or does it depend? Or maybe this is a case where I don't actually need a class member(s)?

I find myself backtracking sometimes because it feels like I'm missing something, like I could be reusing functionality if I passed in parameters instead.

Any feedback would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `callCalculate()` method is doing nothing except calling another method, so it's better that you use only one method to do all your calculation. Also, it's a good practice to make the class members `private` and access them using *getter* and *setter* methods.

Comment: Oh definitely. I wouldn't use the `callCalculate()` method like that in reality. This was dumbed down and was more of a general question. But there are cases where I have classes that do a lot more work, like generating strings and whatnot. So I'll break up responsibilities into different methods.

So along those lines, I was wondering if I should be storing those generated/calculated values as class members, or just using local variables and passing them around.

Comment: If you're planning to use those calculated values *outside* of your class then it's better that you use class members to hold the results, otherwise use local variables to store any intermediate results, which you're not planning to use or manipulate from outside of your class.

Comment: And ya, one more case. If your calculated value needs to shared among multiple class methods then you should use class member variable to hold that calculated value.

Comment: Both cases are green to use. This is somewhat like a 'how to plan a good library' or 'what to do to create a great concept' question. I even store a value into  variable inside a method which is of course won't be used by anything, anyone. Just in case I don't want to change its value, forever. Also, I often store a value from an argument to a property, just in case I want to use it on other method(s). It's just like, what am I going to do next with the value. Sorry if I don't get your question.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, as they have given me some perspective on how to approach it.